Auto-power-up on Mac Mini 2014, but not running macOS
I have an old Mac Mini from 2014, which works perfectly running my 3D printer via Octoprint under Linux.
The only negative is that the host won't turn on when power comes back.
I know this setting is easily changed in macOS, but I also don't want to install a different OS to make a simple change to a power setting.
I've tried booting off the Monterey installer but the power options are not there.
A UPS would be addressing the symptom, not the root cause.
Question: How can I make a Mac turn on automatically when the power returns, when the host is not running an Apple operating system?
Bonus if the answer can be applied in FreeBSD as well as Linux.  I also have a pfsense firewall which really, really should turn on again with power.

This question is specific to Apple hardware, hence why I'm posting it in apple.SE.   The Linux-centric SE sites would simply say "change that settting in the BIOS" but the Apple devices are unique in not having one for the user to modify; hence posting here.

These might be helpful reading, either going some way towards finding a solution (or that no solution exists): https://superuser.com/questions/421415/tools-to-modify-uefi-variables-in-windows-linux https://superuser.com/questions/1346163/how-to-safely-set-change-remove-values-of-efi-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1

This setting is stored in NVRAM and should remain until you reset it. You could boot the Mac off an external OS (I know you don’t want to do that, but it’s the only way I know how to write nvram). Are you sure the battery that maintains NVRAM during a power outage is operations? or implement a robot to poke the button?

@bmike There is an nvram command, but obviously only on macOS.

Under what circumstances is power "going away"? Are you regularly having power outages? Or are you just pulling the plug without shutting down?

That’s precisely my point @benwiggy setting that governs if the firmware restarts itself. No OS needs to be installed for the power on to happen. Something else is missing for this Mac to not start up if the OP didn’t avail themselves of that tool to enable this feature.

@benwiggy We've got builders at work, who have a bad habit of turning circuits off spontaneously.

Even if you do fix the auto-restarting, I'd still recommend a UPS, as sudden switch offs can cause file corruption, and hardware stress. But I'd agree with Mike to check the coin battery first.

@benwiggy fair suggestion - I did try running a 3d printer on a UPS once.  They're quite power heavy, it was not a success.

You should be able to boot into the online recovery console regardless of whether or not you have macOS installed by holding  Opt+Cmd+R or Shift+Opt+Cmd+R  at boot (the first runs the latest compatible version of macOS recovery, the second runs the closest available version to what was originally installed on that machine, per this Apple Support page). Once in that recovery console, you can toggle the option directly with sudo pmset autorestart 1 using the Terminal app.
Again, this worked for my 2018 Mac mini (and has persisted across multiple restarts), but it should also work for the 2014 model. The only other method I've found is to go with the method mentioned in this answer based on a 2010 Mac mini and described in detail at this MythicBeasts page, but that requires some searching for the correct substring for your particular model and requires the setting to be applied at every restart (so you have to dump the code into a startup script).

I'm marking this as accepted because it worked for you.  I haven't had success on this machine though.
